# Excel vlookup matches only if verification is on first column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I notice this problem while using this vlookup function in excel 2016:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"NO MATCHING")
```

So the function will check into the range A:B, and if the match is confirmed, it'll print the value on the second column. Now, my worksheet have got similar values (according to the ones in "A" column of Sheet1) on the column "A" of the Sheet2: if I invert the position of A and B column into the Sheet2 , it will print always the iferror's message "NO MATCHING".

Why this difference?

Comment: Does your `VLOOKUP` return "NO MATCHING" in all cases?

Comment: So you want to look in column B for a match and return column A?

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner. Of course "2" will instead be replaced by "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use INDEX/MATCH as VLOOKUP requires the lookup value to be in left column.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A:A,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"")
```

Comment: Oh, that's what I suspected. Is there some place in Documentation reporting this condition?

Comment: [yes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) It is in there multiple times.

Comment: Just saw translated pages, not the original one. Tnx anyway.